Photon Pun Reloads page on network disconnect on Unity WebGL
I am using Photon Pun 2 in Unity WebGL game. I have a Lobby Screen and a Game Screen. There is a RoomPhoton script to which PhotonView is attached(screenshot attached). The code for reconnection is written in this RoomPhoton script attached to Lobby Screen.  Whenever there is a network disconnection on Game Screen, the page automatically refreshes during the reconnection process and the entire process of opening Lobby Screen followed by Moving to Game Screen is followed. The expected behaivior is to reconnect while keeping the Game Screen open. Even after putting several Debug Logs, I haven't found the reason for this auto refresh of the page.
Any help is much appreaciated.
Here's the code for RoomPhoton script
public class RoomPhoton : MonoBehaviourPunCallbacks, IInRoomCallbacks
{
    public static RoomPhoton  room;
    private PhotonView PV;     
    public int currentScene;  
    public static int screenNumber;

    //Instantiate the Instance of this Class and the PhotonView
    private void Awake()
    {
        if (RoomPhoton.room == null) {
            RoomPhoton.room = this;
        }
        else {
            if (RoomPhoton.room != this) {
                Destroy(RoomPhoton.room.gameObject);
                RoomPhoton.room = this;
            }
        }
        DontDestroyOnLoad(this.gameObject);
        PV = GetComponent < PhotonView > ();
    }

        //Mark the scene number currently active
        public void SetScreenNumber(int num)
    {
        screenNumber = num;
    }

        //Callback received if client disconnects from Photon server
    public override void OnDisconnected(DisconnectCause cause)
    {
        print("OnDisconnected in RoomPhoton  " + cause);
        if (screenNumber == 1) {
            print("OnDisconnected in RoomPhoton 1  ");
            LobbyController.lobbyController.Reconnect();

        }
        else if (screenNumber == 2) {
            print("OnDisconnected in RoomPhoton 2  ");
            PhotonNetwork.ConnectUsingSettings();

        }

    }

    //Utility Functions of Photon Server to Connect to the Rooms
    public override void OnEnable()
    {
        base.OnEnable();
        PhotonNetwork.AddCallbackTarget(this);
        Debug.Log("Enable called");
        SceneManager.sceneLoaded += OnSceneFinishedLoading;
    }

    //Utility Functions of Photon Server to Connect to the Rooms
    public override void OnDisable()
    {
        base.OnDisable();
        PhotonNetwork.RemoveCallbackTarget(this);
        Debug.Log("Disable called");
        SceneManager.sceneLoaded -= OnSceneFinishedLoading;
    }

    //Callback recieved When Scene Is Finished Loading
    void OnSceneFinishedLoading(Scene scene, LoadSceneMode mode)
    {
        print("Inside OnSceneFinishedLoading before ");
        currentScene = scene.buildIndex;
        if (currentScene == 1) {
            CreatePlayer();
            print("Inside OnSceneFinishedLoading after");
        }
    }

PhotonView attached to RoomPhoton GameObect

